What is the way to determine the appropriate rate-control type and tps value in Hyperledger Fabric?
I want to test the performance and scalability of the hyperledger fabric network I created. I am not sure how to set the rateControl and tps values ​​in the caliper benchmark file. In some articles I read (example article) fixed-rate and 50 values ​​are used.
When I use the same values, my throughput (tps) value is fixed as 50 for many tx number values ​​(10, 100, 1000, etc.) in the result reports. Due to the features of the computer I set up and tested the network on, I thought these tests do not strain the network and can easily handle 50 transactions per second. Is this correct? If not, what is the reason?
Also, how should I set the values ​​of these two variables? The first idea that comes to my mind is to do a few tests and find the point where the network is struggling.
I am waiting for your ideas. Thanks in advance.
